# How to get different data in one foor loop?

Tags: python, django-templates

views.py

def index(request):

```
test = Test()
time = test.full_day_time()[0]
today = test.today_forecast()

context={'min_temperature' :  [np.min(today['temperature_2m'][i:i+3]) for i in range(0,24,3)],
         'max_temperature':   [np.max(today['temperature_2m'][i:i+3]) for i in range(0,24,3)],
         'temperature': today['temperature_2m'],
         'time': time,
         'range': range(6)
         }

return render(request, 'new_base.html', context)
```

I want to get something like this,
but this doesn't work

index.html

```
{% for i in range %}

  <p>{{min_temperature.i}}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need range variable in view or template.

Just use as below.

```
{% for i in min_temperature %}

    {{i}}

{% endfor %}
```

You can pick specific elements too.

```
{% for i in min_temperature %}

{% if forloop.counter == 2 %} 
    {{i}}
{% endif %} 

{% endfor %}
```

Or like,

```
{{ min_temperature.0 }} 

{{ min_temperature.index_you_want_to_access }}
```

Or like,

```
{{ min_temperature.0.model_field_name }}

{{ min_temperature.index_you_want_to_access.model_field_name }}
```

Comment: You can loop through lists like that.

Comment: But in for loop I also need max_temperature.i

Comment: You can also access like ``` {{ max_temperature.0 }}   {{ max_temperature.1 }}    .